# navbar collapse class not working in bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

3

I did some modification in navbar. now the navbar-headershowing but from collapse navbar-collapse not showing. Below is my code. Where I am wrong ??

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am using angular

Comment: You need to add jQuery, proper.js, and bootstrap.js in the same order that I have written.

Comment: You also removed html of `navbar-toggle`. you should add 
`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>` just before `navbar-brand`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap framework needs Jquery to work on JS side, so before all your js files try to import it:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```